# How to Drag a view to top and bottom like this in Android?

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, uiswitch, swipe-gesture

I want to perform an action when user turned off or on by dragging the view and I don't want it to stop in middle.

[image]

Any Idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to perform dragging, you have to use motion layout for it, Click [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout) for more reference.